# Code profiling, what does "Machine Code Sinking" and "Virtual Register Rewriter" mean?

Tags: c++, arm, profiling, compiler-optimization

Clang reports (using `-ftime-trace`) that one of my files on arm v8 takes over 100m due to the optimization (`OptFunction`) steps "`Machine Code Sinking`" and "`Virtual Register Rewriter`".

However I have no idea what to do with this information.  My objective is to reduce the build time.  On arm v7 the same function only takes ~6 minutes.

- Is there something I'm missing here?
- Is there a way I can use this information to modify my code the impact on these steps?
- I've opened the profile in [Speedscope](https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope) too but there's no additional info.  Are there other tools that might help more?
- Is there more info I can provide to better ask for help (file size, number of defined symbols, *etc*)?

Some additional detail:

- This function is in generated code, so there are limited options when it comes to restructuring overhauling
- On gcc 8.3 arm v8 it takes a similar amount of time
- On clang `x86_64` a similar function (I don't have this exact code building on `x86_64` :( yet) takes a fraction of the time.

Tracing data:
[image: Trace shoing the huge OptFunction]

Comment: In compiler terminology, one meaning of the word "sinking" is moving code out of a loop to happen once after the loop.  (e.g. hoist a loop-invariant load to before the loop, sink a store).  But that's probably *not* what's meant here, because that code-motion would happen on a target-independent representation of the program logic, like LLVM's IR, not in terms of final machine code.